# How To Re-Train model ML .NET

Tags: c#, ml.net

I have created a project to classify images using LbfgsMaximumEntropy algorithm.
Step by step that to do:

//Prepare the data
var images = LoadImagesFromDirectory(folder: assetsRelativePath, useFolderNameAsLabel: true);

```
        //Load the images
        var imageData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(images);

        //Blance the data
        var shuffledData = mlContext.Data.ShuffleRows(imageData);

        var trainSplit = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(data: shuffledData, testFraction: 0.10);

        var trainSet = trainSplit.TrainSet;
        var testSet = trainSplit.TestSet;
```

var trainer = mlContext
.MulticlassClassification
.Trainers
.LbfgsMaximumEntropy(
labelColumnName: "LabelAsKey",
featureColumnName: "softmax2_pre_activation");  //"softmax2_pre_activation" for Inception v1
//IDataView transformedData = dataPrepTransformer.Transform(trainSet);

```
        var trainingPipeline = 
             mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: "LabelAsKey", inputColumnName: "Label")
             .Append(mlContext.Transforms.LoadImages(outputColumnName: "image_object", imageFolder: @"E:\ThienNguyen\Sources\ML\ML.Net\DeepLearning_ImageClassification_Binary\DeepLearning_ImageClassification_Binary\assets\", inputColumnName: nameof(ImageData.ImagePath)))
                        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(outputColumnName: "image_object_resized",
                                                                    imageWidth: ImageSettingsForTFModel.ImageWidth, imageHeight: ImageSettingsForTFModel.ImageHeight,
                                                                    inputColumnName: "image_object"))
                        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: "input", inputColumnName: "image_object_resized",
                                                                    interleavePixelColors: ImageSettingsForTFModel.ChannelsLast,
                                                                    offsetImage: ImageSettingsForTFModel.Mean))
            .Append(mlContext.Model.LoadTensorFlowModel(inputTensorFlowModelFilePath).
                                ScoreTensorFlowModel(outputColumnNames: new[] { "softmax2_pre_activation" },
                                                    inputColumnNames: new[] { "input" },
                                                    addBatchDimensionInput: true))
          
            //.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion
            //.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabelValue", "PredictedLabel"))
            ;
        ITransformer dataPrepTransformer = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainSet);
        IDataView transformedData = dataPrepTransformer.Transform(trainSet);

        var model = trainingPipeline.Append(trainer)
              .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabelValue", "PredictedLabel"))
            .Fit(transformedData)
            ;

        ClassifySingleImage(mlContext, model);

        // Save Data Prep transformer
        mlContext.Model.Save(dataPrepTransformer, trainSet.Schema, "data_preparation_pipeline.zip");
  
        // Save Trained Model
        mlContext.Model.Save(model, trainSet.Schema, "model.zip");
```

**Then I reload the trained model and extract this model todo**
DataViewSchema dataPrepPipelineSchema, modelSchema;

```
        // Load data preparation pipeline
        ITransformer dataPrepPipeline = mlContext.Model.Load("data_preparation_pipeline.zip", out dataPrepPipelineSchema);

        // Load trained model
        ITransformer trainedModel = mlContext.Model.Load("model.zip", out modelSchema);

        // Extract trained model parameters
        var originalModelParameters =
                    ((Microsoft.ML.Data.TransformerChain<Microsoft.ML.ITransformer>)trainedModel).LastTransformer;
```

But the return result of originalModelParameters is nullable and I can not continue to retrain the model

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastTransformer = (trainedModel as TransformerChain<ITransformer>).LastTransformer as ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer<object>;

var originalModelParameters = lastTransformer.Model as MaximumEntropyModelParameters;
```

You must typecast your lastTransformer to `ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer<TModel>` in order to extract the feature columnname and type.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.isinglefeaturepredictiontransformer-1?view=ml-dotnet

From there you can extract the parameters from the Model property of the pre-trained model. Typecast the Model to your learner's parameter class (in this case MaximumEntropyModelParameters).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/retrain-model-ml-net

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.